# How to overcome RealmMigrationNeededException error on android app

Tags: kotlin, migration, realm

When I click on launcher icon of my android app, its crashes immediately. I check logcat error, its shows Migration is required due to the following errors: - Property 'PrintJobData.jobPageCount' has been removed.I'm using Realm database and language is kotlin. How to overcome this issue.

private val realmConfig: RealmConfiguration = RealmConfiguration.Builder()

```
        .name("database.realm")
```

//            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()

```
        .schemaVersion(1)

        .build()


private var realm: Realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can delete your realm if a migration is needed:

```
.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
```

or you can write a custom migration for your realm and each change you make to your database MUST be handled in migration.
NOTE: remember after your changes to your database you have to update `schemaVersion` and also add your custom migration to `RealmConfiguration.Builder()` like bellow:

```
val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .name("yourRealmName.realm")
        .schemaVersion(2)
        .migration(CustomMigration())
        .build()
```

you can learn how to write migration from [this](https://medium.com/anycode/android-automatic-migration-of-realm-schema-version-6d6e862ea8ff) and the original [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-legacy/docs/kotlin/latest/)